# R list of character vectors to list of lists

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an input that is like:

```
library(tibble)
input = as.tibble(["test1/data/data.rds", "test1/settings/setting.txt", "test2/stuff.rds"])
```

I am trying to turn this into a table with multiple columns so I want:

```
test1 | data | data.rds
test1 | settings | setting.txt
test2 | stuff.rds | NA
```

I can split the data by:

```
library(stringr)
split = stringr::str_split(input$value, '/')
```

that gives me a list of character vectors.

```
result = as_tibble(split)
```

gives me back a one column frame of character vectors rather than a multi-column construct?

What do I need to do to make it multi column? Blanks should be NAs.

This is different from previous questions because the number of columns is variable and not fixed

Comment: You can use `separate_rows(input, value)`

Comment: that gives me a single column data frame rather than a 3+ column frame?